# Play .ulaw files in Windows media player?

Tags: audio, windows-media-player

Does anyone know of a free or shareware plugin for Windows Media Player that will allow me to play `.ulaw` audio files?

Answer (score 3):

µ-law is an old audio type mostly found in QuickTime videos.
Install [CCCP Codec Pack](http://www.cccp-project.net/) and follow the instructions from wiki below:

Go to CCCP's start menu folder -> Filters -> ffdshow audio. Select Codecs on the left side. Find the Audio Stream codec in the list, then set the *Decoder* column from *disabled* to *libavcodec*.

After doing the above your file (µ-law/a-law) should play.